Локализация обязательных полей на странице "Задать вопрос"
Собственно, на принтскрине всё видно:

Непереведённые фразы:

Required fields


required


Предложил переводы:

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/20450

Required fields


Обязательные поля


https://ru.traducir.win/strings/20453

required


обязательное поле




Утвердил. Хотя добавка "поле" там, где его нет, может быть не очень хорошей идеей. Текущая сборка 2024.5.23.9693

@αλεχολυτ, а как же писать без "поле"? "обязательно" или "обязательное"?

Можно и так. Дело в том, что переводы обычно не привязаны (на уровне transifex) к какому-то кокретному функционалу сайта. А это значит, что где-то в другом месте может пролезть перевод для "required" как "обязательное поле", где "поля" вообще никакого нет. Наверное, самый яркий пример был с about.
